# C++ Access violation?

Tags: c++, access-violation

Why am I getting an access violation reading location 0xC0000005 here if the same code works like a charm when I coding in linux?

```
if(nodo->izq!=NULL) //nodo is a class or struct and "sig" is a pointer of the same kind
    VaciarAux(nodo->izq);
```

Is there any way of getting this done without that unhandled exception?
assert will do the trick?

here is the function

```
void Arbol<T>::VaciarAux(Nodo<T> * &nodo)
{
    if(nodo->izq!=NULL)
        VaciarAux(nodo->izq);
    if(nodo->der!=NULL)
        VaciarAux(nodo->der);
    if(nodo->izq == NULL && nodo->der ==NULL)
    {
        actual = nodo;
        nodo=NULL;
        delete actual;
        contador--;
    }
```

Comment: `assert` is only meant as a sanity check for your program. Any checks done using `assert` are supposed to not even be present in production code. You're probably reading unintialized memory somewhere, thus your NULL check passes but then you reach into random memory areas. However, you should post more code to help with assessing your problem.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question needed for an adequate reply. The access violation could be for any reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "assert will do the trick"? Always be very specific when you ask questions.

Comment: I defined NULL as 0 at the header.
This function is a recursive one, what it does is to clean a tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely because `nodo` itself is an invalid pointer. The `->` dereferencing would then cause a problem.

You need to check the things that could possibly affect that value (buffer overflows causing corruption, having set to NULL for some reason).

Note that:

```
if (nodo->izq != NULL)
```

does *not* check if the `nodo` variable is NULL but rather if the `izq` member of what `nodo` points to is NULL.

If you simply want to do nothing if `nodo` itself is NULL, you could put at the start:

```
if (nodo == NULL) return;
```

but I still think you'd be much better off tracking back to the source of the problem rather than just fixing one symptom.

---

I think the problem is with the way you are processing the tree. You are effectively doing:

```
def delTree (node):
    if node.left != NULL:
        delTree (node.left)
    if node.right != NULL:
        delTree (node.right)
    if node.left == NULL and node.right == NULL:
        delete node and whatever else you have to do
```

The main problem with that is that `delTree (node.left)` means that you'll get the exact problem you're seeing if the tree is empty since the first thing you try to do is dereference the NULL root node.

The more usual approach is to first recur the children unconditionally (with a NULL protector) then process the node itself, something like:

```
def delTree (node):
    if node == NULL:
        return
    delTree (node.left)
    delTree (node.right)
    delete node and whatever else you have to do
```

This will correctly handle an empty tree and still correctly delete all children before the parent. And it just *looks* more elegant, which is one of the reasons to use recursion in the first place :-)

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to turn that back into C++.

Comment: so is it a bad practice to initialize a tree with a null root?

Comment: No, that's actually fairly standard - it's an empty tree. I think I see what you're getting at now (despite the language difficulties) - I'll update the answer.

Comment: I need to return true of false in this line if (nodo->izq != NULL)
that's where I decide to follow the tree branch, left or right.

Comment: So this is a bad practice, Don't know why they teach that at the university

Comment: lol, I'm trying my best here with the language,
I code those lines (adapted) to my source, but the error is still going...

Comment: @HoNgOuRu, don't get me wrong, your language skills are just fine. I was alluding to the "unusual" variable names like `nodo`, `izq`, `der` and `contador`. Up until the point you said you were deleting a tree, the code made no sense to me. I suppose I should have just checked Google Translate and it would have given me the Spanish->English translation. Though interestingly, it refuses to translate "der", insisting instead that the English "right" is "derecho".

Comment: THANK YOU ALL.
THE SOLUTION TO THIS:

Comment: if(nodo==NULL)
  return;
 VaciarAux(nodo->izq);
 VaciarAux(nodo->der);
 delete nodo;

Comment: @paxdiablo question: you mentioned that `delTree(node.left)` does not set `node.left` to NULL, but since he's passing that pointer by reference, and he does do a `node = NULL;` when deleting the node, shouldn't that affect the value of `node.left` in the previous recursive call?

Comment: Absolutely, correct, @Jason, I have to admit I was wrong there, that sneaky little `&` was hiding from me, I'm sure :-) I've removed that erroneous part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As pax says it's probably a bad pointer. In Linux there may not be strict virtual memory rules as when running the code somewhere else (also depends on the compiler). So in the Linux case it might be working but it might actually be doing something you don't expect.

Comment: Linux has strict memory rules. However it might be that on Linux he has a valid random pointer

Comment: Yeah since malloc allocates based on pages that pointer can be within a page boundary that is valid. By strict I mean that in Windows some areas called by malloc are marked with PROTECTED so you can't actually use them after they are freed (in some cases) or before they are malloced

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into how you are creating a `Nodo` type (i.e., look at its default constructor ... it should have one since it's a class/struct that contains pointers).  For instance, if you are not initializing the members of a `Nodo` type so that the two pointer members are initially `NULL` whenever a `Nodo` object is created, then they could have any indeterminant value such that the tests for `NULL` values inside of `Arbol<T>::VaciarAux` will fail.  For instance, a new `Nodo` would end up with pointers initialized to some random value, but those random memory values contained in the pointer-members of `Nodo` are not valid locations accessible in memory.  Then when you test whether the pointers are `NULL`, the test comes out false, and you attempt to dereference them in the next recursive call to `Arbol<T>::VaciarAux`, causing an access violation.

Comment: endeed, I am initializing them with a NULL value at the default constructor

Comment: template <class DNodo>
            class Nodo
            {
                public:
                Nodo(const DNodo  datoPasado,
                     Nodo<DNodo> *izqPasado=NULL,NULL
                     Nodo<DNodo> *derPasado=NULL)
                      : dato(datoPasado),izq(izqPasado),der(derPasado),equi(0){}
                      Nodo();

Comment: How many nodes are in your tree?  Does this access violation seem to happen randomly, or does it happen after a certain number of nodes?

Comment: As it is a recursive method, I shouldn't be asking if the left or right son were NULL, that drives to an access violation .
Rather than doing that I did what @paxdiablo suggested